# How can I get Subliminal to work?

Tags: video, download-manager, subtitle

How can I get Subliminal to work and then integrate it with a file manager?

I have downloaded Subliminal which is a program that downloads movie subtitles.But when I test it at the console with a movie that I know has an English subtitle, I get an unsatisfactory response:

```
alan@alan-Latitude-D530:~$ subliminal -l en la fin du jour.avi
usage: subliminal -l LANGUAGE [LANGUAGE ...] [-s] [-c CACHE_FILE]
                  [-p PROVIDER [PROVIDER ...]] [-m MIN_SCORE] [-a AGE] [-h]
                  [-f] [--addic7ed-username USERNAME]
                  [--addic7ed-password PASSWORD] [-q | -v]
                  [--log-file LOG_FILE] [--color] [--debug] [--version]
                  [--help]
                  PATH [PATH ...]
subliminal: error: too few arguments
```

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem until I ran into [subliminal documentation site](http://subliminal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). According to it the previous command should be :

```
subliminal -l en -- the.smurf2.x264.mp4
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Now if only they would make that info available in the help.

Comment: can you explain please why `--` must be used?

Comment: very odd, but it works. but its capacity of finding the proper subs  it's another matter

Answer (score 1):

```
subliminal -l en the.smurf2.x264.mp4
```

This will download the subtitle in the current folder .

"-l" sets the subtitle language, "en" (English)

Be careful for the name of your movie , the spaces !

Comment: alan@alan-Latitude-D530:~$ subliminal -l en the.smurf2.x264.mp4
usage: subliminal -l LANGUAGE [LANGUAGE ...] [-s] [-c CACHE_FILE]
                  [-p PROVIDER [PROVIDER ...]] [-m MIN_SCORE] [-a AGE] [-h]
                  [-f] [--addic7ed-username USERNAME]
                  [--addic7ed-password PASSWORD] [-q | -v]
                  [--log-file LOG_FILE] [--color] [--debug] [--version]
                  [--help]
                  PATH [PATH ...]
subliminal: error: too few arguments
alan@alan-Latitude-D530:~$

Comment: i gave an example of the smurf , its not correct

Comment: Is there anyone out there who is actually using Subliminal successfully?!:

Comment: This worked for me. I'm actually using Subliminal on the Mac, and this solved the same issue.

Comment: @ALAN - yes it 'works' with a command like the one presented in the other answer. I have even added it in a KDE/Dolphin context menu  in  a `.desktop` file (kde service) containg the line `Exec=konsole --hold --workdir %P -e subliminal -l en -- %F` , and it works as it is supposed to I guess. But the program's ability to get the good sub is very limited compared to vlsub of VLC: that is, I haven't got a good one yet :)